# Java Selenium why click function doesn't works?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, click

Why `click()` doesn't works?

website:

```
String startPage = "http://www.domiporta.pl/mieszkanie/sprzedam?Localization=dolno%C5%9Bl%C4%85skie&PageNumber=24&SortingOrder=InsertionDate";
```

**Code:**

```
List<WebElement> RowsMain = driver.findElements(By.className("detail-card__heading"));
for(int i=0;i<RowsMain.size();i++){
    driver.get(startPage);
    List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.className("detail-card__heading"));
    List<WebElement> cols=new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    cols=rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("div"));
    for(WebElement col:cols) {
        col.click();
    }
}
```

Why click doesn't workS?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Does it work on some columns but not others? Does your code run fine but nothing happens? What happens when you step through the code? `click()` works just fine in java, so you'll need to provide more information to specifically what you're seeing.

Comment: No error - I'dlike to go into each page but nothing has happened.

Answer (score 0):

It is error because you navigate out of the current page, so DOM has been destroyed. The solution is simple, find the elements every time when you navigate out of the page. See code below.

```
int rowCount = driver.findElements(By.className("detail-card__heading")).size();
for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++){
    List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.className("detail-card__heading"));
    int colsCount = rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("div")).size();
    for(int j=0;j<colsCount; j++) {
        rows = driver.findElements(By.className("detail-card__heading"));
        List<WebElement>cols = rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("div"));
        cols.get(j).click();
        driver.get(startPage);
    }
}
```